# Decrypt json file aes-128-ctr using openssl

Tags: encryption, openssl

I'm having an issue trying to decrypt a json file using openssl command.

I have all these infos:

- cipher: aes-128-ctr
- cipherparams:

  - iv: 14ba8.........c2161
  - ciphertext :  cd1d9e5e1.....8941100
  - kdf: pbkdf2,  kdfparams: { c:10240, dklen:32, prf:hmac-sha256, salt: a9e493.......5d6fb8a76 }
  - mac : 2080abdb3c86.....c7b7b93

so I'm trying to decrypt the ciphertext with following command:

```
$ openssl enc -aes-128-ctr -d -in text_in.enc -pbkdf2 -salt -iter 10240  -iv "14ba8......c2161" -S "a9e493.......5d6fb8a76" -pass pass:<mypin>
```

In text_in.enc file there is the ciphertext:

```
$ cat text_in.enc
cd1d9e5e1.....8941100
```

but when I use openssl command I get "bad magic number" error.

```
$ openssl enc -aes-128-ctr -d -in text_in.enc -pbkdf2 -salt -iter 10240  -iv "14ba8......c2161" -S "a9e493.......075d6fb8a76" -pass pass:<mypin>
bad magic number
```

Is this the right way to decrypt these data?

Comment: Considering that your JSON file contains a MAC which is not a byproduct of CTR mode I think there is information missing. Additionally, this question is not programming related and not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The `openssl enc` tool in decryption mode `-d` does not support providing the salt on the command line. Unless you indicate `-nosalt`, it expects the file to begin with a magic number that is `Salted__` in ASCII, followed by the salt bytes. Your ciphertext file does not contain that information at the start, hence the error.

You could "manually" add the missing magic number and salt bytes at the front, by doing something like this:

```
$ cat <(printf Salted__) <(printf a9e493...075d6fb8a76 | xxd -r -p) text_in.enc | openssl enc -aes-128-ctr -d -iter 10240 -iv 14ba8...c2161 -pass pass:<mypin>
```

`xxd -r` is used to convert your hex string salt into bytes.

Note that the option `-pbkdf2` is implied when using the option `-iter` and that no quotes are required around the hex strings.

Comment: Hi Reinier, I've tried with this command but it doesn't decrypt as expected.
I returns always binary decrypted data.